# Error in simplexml_load_string function

Tags: php, simplexml

I have the following string in a variable php

```
<root>
  <id></id>
  <title>Maarch Capture Connector</title>
  <width>400</width>
  <height>250</height>
  <center>true</center>
  <fields>
    <node>
        <type>comboBox</type>
        <id>ingoing</id>
        <label>Courrier</label>
        <autocomplete>false</autocomplete>
        <values>
            <node>
                <id>Y</id>
                <label>Arrivée</label>
            </node>
            <node>
                <id>N</id>
                <label>Départ</label>
            </node>
        </values>
        <default_value>Y</default_value>
        <show_id>false</show_id>
        <mandatory>true</mandatory>
    </node>
    <node>
        <type>comboBox</type>
        <id>priority</id>
        <label>Priorité</label>
        <autocomplete>false</autocomplete>
        <values>
            <node>
                <id>0</id>
                <label>Priorité trés haute</label>
            </node>
            <node>
                <id>1</id>
                <label>Priorité haute</label>
            </node>
            <node>
                <id>2</id>
                <label>Priorité normale</label>
            </node>
            <node>
                <id>3</id>
                <label>Priorité basse</label>
            </node>
        </values>
        <default_value>2</default_value>
        <show_id>false</show_id>
        <mandatory>true</mandatory>
    </node>
    <node>
        <type>comboBox</type>
        <id>services</id>
        <label>Service</label>
        <autocomplete>false</autocomplete>
        <values>
            <node>
                <id>9</id>
                <label>Compay SEGUNDO</label>
            </node>
            <node>
                <id>10</id>
                <label>Contract 1 for Eric SPRITZ : Life insurance</label>
            </node>
            <node>
                <id>13</id>
                <label>Contract 1 for Thomas BECK : Life insurance</label>
            </node>
            <node>
                <id>11</id>
                <label>Contract 2 for Eric SPRITZ : Home insurance</label>
            </node>
            <node>
                <id>14</id>
                <label>Contract 2 for Thomas BECK : Home insurance</label>
            </node>
            <node>
                <id>12</id>
                <label>Contract 3 for Eric SPRITZ : Car insurance</label>
            </node>
            <node>
                <id>15</id>
                <label>Contract 3 for Thomas BECK : Car insurance</label>
            </node>
            <node>
                <id>8</id>
                <label>Edith PIAF</label>
            </node>
            <node>
                <id>1</id>
                <label>Eric SPRITZ</label>
            </node>
            <node>
                <id>5</id>
                <label>Joao GILBERTO</label>
            </node>
            <node>
                <id>6</id>
                <label>Luciano PAVAROTTI</label>
            </node>
            <node>
                <id>7</id>
                <label>Maria BETHANIA</label>
            </node>
            <node>
                <id>16</id>
                <label>MARTIN HR file</label>
            </node>
            <node>
                <id>17</id>
                <label>SMITH HR file</label>
            </node>
            <node>
                <id>3</id>
                <label>Teresa CRISTINA</label>
            </node>
            <node>
                <id>2</id>
                <label>Thomas BECK</label>
            </node>
            <node>
                <id>4</id>
                <label>Tom JOBIM</label>
            </node>
        </values>
        <show_id>false</show_id>
        <mandatory>true</mandatory>
    </node>
</fields>
</root>
```

When I try to read with simplexml_load_string function

```
$xmlForm = simplexml_load_string($string);
```

I get this error

> Entity: line 1: parser error : Start tag expected, '<' not found

I don't understand what is succeeding.

Comment: Try to add a `<?xml version='1.0'?>` and show us how you initialize your string.

Comment: Try adding a `<?xml` PI header. Look for invisible chars at the file beginning; use a hexeditor.

Comment: I pasted it into xmlvalidation.com and it reported now errors, so there's probably some extra characters.

Answer (score 0):

Try replacing the empty tag `<id></id>` with `<id/>`

While technically correct, it might be tripping up the parser.

Other than that, it looks like well formed XML to me.

Comment: I don't think this is self closed tag problem at this point. look at the error message...

Answer (score 0):

Execution this code :

```
<?php

$str =<<<XML_CONTENT
<?xml version='1.0'?>
<root>
  <id></id>
  <title>Maarch Capture Connector</title>
  <width>400</width>
  <height>250</height>
  <center>true</center>
  <fields>
    <node>
        <type>comboBox</type>
        <id>ingoing</id>
        <label>Courrier</label>
        <autocomplete>false</autocomplete>
        <values>
            <node>
                <id>Y</id>
                <label>Arrivée</label>
            </node>
            <node>
                <id>N</id>
                <label>Départ</label>
            </node>
        </values>
        <default_value>Y</default_value>
        <show_id>false</show_id>
        <mandatory>true</mandatory>
    </node>
    <node>
        <type>comboBox</type>
        <id>priority</id>
        <label>Priorité</label>
        <autocomplete>false</autocomplete>
        <values>
            <node>
                <id>0</id>
                <label>Priorité trés haute</label>
            </node>
            <node>
                <id>1</id>
                <label>Priorité haute</label>
            </node>
            <node>
                <id>2</id>
                <label>Priorité normale</label>
            </node>
            <node>
                <id>3</id>
                <label>Priorité basse</label>
            </node>
        </values>
        <default_value>2</default_value>
        <show_id>false</show_id>
        <mandatory>true</mandatory>
    </node>
    <node>
        <type>comboBox</type>
        <id>services</id>
        <label>Service</label>
        <autocomplete>false</autocomplete>
        <values>
            <node>
                <id>9</id>
                <label>Compay SEGUNDO</label>
            </node>
            <node>
                <id>10</id>
                <label>Contract 1 for Eric SPRITZ : Life insurance</label>
            </node>
            <node>
                <id>13</id>
                <label>Contract 1 for Thomas BECK : Life insurance</label>
            </node>
            <node>
                <id>11</id>
                <label>Contract 2 for Eric SPRITZ : Home insurance</label>
            </node>
            <node>
                <id>14</id>
                <label>Contract 2 for Thomas BECK : Home insurance</label>
            </node>
            <node>
                <id>12</id>
                <label>Contract 3 for Eric SPRITZ : Car insurance</label>
            </node>
            <node>
                <id>15</id>
                <label>Contract 3 for Thomas BECK : Car insurance</label>
            </node>
            <node>
                <id>8</id>
                <label>Edith PIAF</label>
            </node>
            <node>
                <id>1</id>
                <label>Eric SPRITZ</label>
            </node>
            <node>
                <id>5</id>
                <label>Joao GILBERTO</label>
            </node>
            <node>
                <id>6</id>
                <label>Luciano PAVAROTTI</label>
            </node>
            <node>
                <id>7</id>
                <label>Maria BETHANIA</label>
            </node>
            <node>
                <id>16</id>
                <label>MARTIN HR file</label>
            </node>
            <node>
                <id>17</id>
                <label>SMITH HR file</label>
            </node>
            <node>
                <id>3</id>
                <label>Teresa CRISTINA</label>
            </node>
            <node>
                <id>2</id>
                <label>Thomas BECK</label>
            </node>
            <node>
                <id>4</id>
                <label>Tom JOBIM</label>
            </node>
        </values>
        <show_id>false</show_id>
        <mandatory>true</mandatory>
    </node>
</fields>
</root>
XML_CONTENT;

$xmlForm = simplexml_load_string($str);

print_r($xmlForm);

echo "Everything is fine !";

?>
```

In a PHP online machine like : [PHP online](http://www.compileonline.com/execute_php_online.php)

work fine, so you could have a problem with your string initialization (bad invisible caraters...?)

Note: Adding the XML header tag is a best effort and should not be forgotten

Comment: I forgot to mention that I am trying to install the [Maarch Capture Connector](http://wiki.maarch.org/Socle_Technique_/_Outils_annexes_/_Maarch_Capture_Connector)

Comment: what is the relation with the problem ..? How do you initialize tour XML string .?

Answer (score 0):

I have solved my problem. My XML String was fine...The problem was in other files of [Maarch Enterprise](http://www.maarch.org/en/projects/entreprise) that I had modified. Sorry for late reply and Thanks for helping :)